# Python - Remove excel sheets using Filter()

Tags: python, excel, filter

I would like to only include certain sheets in an excel using the Filter() function.

This is my code so far:

```
import win32com.client as win32
from pathlib import Path

win32c = win32.constants

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:/Prueba/GOOG.xlsm")

def included(sheet_name):
    l = ['Report_Data', 'Report_Main']
    if sheet_name in l:
        return True

wb.__Sheets__ = filter(included, [sheet.Name for sheet in wb.Sheets]) # wb.__Sheets__ doesn't work of course...
```

My guess is that I need to properly access the Sheets attribute from workbook object and then the filter setup should do it.  I tried "**Sheets**" for instance, but doesn't seem to work (also does not throw an error...).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the filter process you're using, you don't need to open the workbook. You can load the file using openpyxl and get the sheet names.

Try this code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Prueba/GOOG.xlsm')
print("All Sheets:", wb.sheetnames)

def included(sheet_name):
    l = ['Report_Data', 'Report_Main']
    if sheet_name in l:
        return True

wb.__Sheets__ = filter(included, wb.sheetnames) # wb.__Sheets__ doesn't work of course..

print(list(wb.__Sheets__))
```

If you prefer to stay with Win32 and have Excel actually open, you can use this code:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import win32com
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True

wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:/Prueba/GOOG.xlsm")
print("All Sheets:",[wb.Sheets(i+1).Name for i in range(wb.Sheets.Count)])

def included(sheet_name):
    l = ['Report_Data', 'Report_Main']
    if sheet_name in l:
        return True

ShtList = filter(included, [wb.Sheets(i+1).Name for i in range(wb.Sheets.Count)]) 

print(list(ShtList))

excel.Quit()
```

Here is the complete code to delete the extra sheets and save the workbook as a new file.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import win32com
import win32com.client as win32
from shutil import copyfile

excel = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True

filename = "C:/Prueba/GOOG.xlsm"
filenamenew = "C:/Prueba/GOOG.New.xlsm"

copyfile(filename, filenamenew)

wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filenamenew)
print("All Sheets:",[wb.Sheets(i+1).Name for i in range(wb.Sheets.Count)])

def remove(sheet_name):
    l = ['Report_Data', 'Report_Main']
    if not sheet_name in l:
        return True

ShtList = list(filter(remove, [wb.Sheets(i+1).Name for i in range(wb.Sheets.Count)]))

print("DelLst:",ShtList)

excel.DisplayAlerts = False  # new prompt for delete

for s in ShtList:
   print("del", s)
   wb.Worksheets(s).Delete()

wb.Save()

excel.DisplayAlerts = True
excel.Quit()
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know what the solution would look like if I wanted to use win32 client by any chance? Just curious (my workplace has an old version of openpyxl and updating it to recent one is very tedious)

Comment: Would you know how would it go to save down the "new" workbook (i.e., with filtered sheets)?